# how to avoid using TempData

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

I'm new to asp.net mvc, so please bear with me.

I'm using TempData when I redirect to another Action and I don't want to "dirty" the URL with information. For example:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ConfirmationEmailSent()
{
    if (TempData["Username"] != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Username = TempData["Username"];
        return View("ConfirmationEmailSent");
    }
    return View("Error");
}
```

So far so good, the user gets a simple and innocent looking web page with some message containing his username. But if the user hits the 'refresh' button then he gets the "Error" view, because TempDate is unavailable.
I would like to have the ability to redirect to action with information not presented in the querystring and also that if the user hits the refresh button then he gets just the same page.
Any ideas how to do this? (without session)

Thank you.

Comment: why not receive username as parameter in your actionresult. send the user name from calling function

Comment: because it will mess up the url. instead of: www.mywebsite.com/account/confirmation_sent I'll get: www.mywebsite.com/account/confirmation_sent?username=blabla. I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Then send a viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a way to have information persist across more than one request in a way that is associated with the browser. QueryString and Session are your two best options.

If the view is the result of a form post, you *could* make it a hidden input, but the user will get a prompt when they refresh (do you want to resubmit form?), but this is not good, as you should be doing a Post/Redirect/Get (PRG).

Erick

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like cookies would do what you want. Then just delete them when you're done (or don't set an expiration date on them, in which case the browser will delete them for you when the session completes).